# Where is the DNS cache stored for Ubuntu?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, curl, libcurl

Where can I find the actual DNS cache storage on a Ubuntu file system?

I have a PHP script which uses libcurl to crawl several hundred pages on the same domain, and I have it set to use a global DNS cache, and set the DNS cache timeout to 5 minutes (300 seconds), which definitely speeds things up, because a few of the calls were hanging due to name resolution issues (too many name resolution requests for the same domain, the server must have been rejecting/hanging on some).

Another question I had is, is it possible to have a permanent storage place for domain to IP address mappings, so that you don't even have to use DNS caching in libcurl?  can I use /etc/resolv.conf to store an external domain name and map it to it's IP address, would this work?

I've been in in web development for awhile now so I'm pretty familiar with the linux command line and messing with configurations/settings but I haven't been able to find an answer to this question

I guess I could just make the actual libcurl requests use the IP address of the websites I'm pulling from, but I'd rather have it use the domain name for logging purposes so that I can monitor for any issues with requests hanging

Comment: `is it possible to have a permanent storage place for domain to IP address mappings` - yes, it's called a [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) and its probably at `/etc/hosts`

Comment: You might get better answers at http://askubuntu.com/ (Ubuntu Stack Exchange site).

Comment: the /etc/hosts file works for external domains/IP addresses though?  Will libcurl use this /etc/hosts file before attempting to resolve a domain name though?

Comment: It's not about libcurl, or any other application. The hosts file is for the operating system, when libcurl wants a DNS lookup it asks the operating system for it, and hence the hosts file will do the job. If you're really concerned, you could just create associative array in PHP of `hostname => ip address` and use that.

Comment: But what I'm trying to get at, is when libcurl asks the operating system for the DNS lookup, will it first answer with a response from the /etc/hosts file before attempting to resolve a domain name?

Comment: @DaveRandom yes, put the name to IP map in the PHP app, it shouldn't be in the system wide hosts file!

Comment: Why do we have 4 close votes? I don't think this is offtopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're looking for the DNS cache maintained by curl (and not a system wide global cache) because unless you're running a caching resolver (LDNS server), the responsibility to cache DNS records falls on the applications.

Secondly, you can use `/etc/hosts` to store mappings. If you're resolver library isn't preferring /etc/hosts over a DNS lookup, you need to change the order of lookup in [/etc/host.conf](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap5sec39.html). You should see a line like:

```
order hosts,bind
```

`hosts` here tells the `gethostbyname`, etc. resolver library utilities to look at the `/etc/hosts` file first.

Comment: thank you!  I can use IP to sub-domain mappings as well right?

Comment: Do you mean sub-domain to IP, if so yes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `/etc/hosts` to store IP and hosts

Comment: Will libcurl use the /etc/hosts file before attempting to resolve a domain name though?